# how to fix missing template , application/create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i keep getting this missing template error

```
" Missing template listings/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/codio/workspace/app/views" * "/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views" * "/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/commontator-4.10.3/app/views" * "/home/codio/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/devise-a9d90503e903/app/views" * "/home/codio/.bundler/ruby/2.2.0/koudoku-9e73e64e5520/app/views" * "/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/mailboxer-0.12.4/app/views"
```

,anytime i tried to create an object,after a couple of search in stack overflow , some suggest to redirect or render , initially in my create action , there was no explicit redirect and after object creation the redirect was done to the show page (the intended behavior).Tried both solutions , but still getting the same error and in my understanding there's no need to have a corresponding views for the create action.

How do i got the create action redirect to the show page without creating a 
 a view?.

```
    listings_controller.rb
    class ListingsController < ApplicationController
       ...

      def create
        @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
        if @listing.save
          if params[:images]
              params[:images].each { |image|
                @listing.pictures.create(image: image)
              }
           end
         (@users - [current_user]).each do |user|
            Notification.create(recipient: user, actor: current_user, action: "posted", notifiable: @listing)
         end   
         flash[:notice]= "L'annonce #{@listing.listing_number} a eté publiee avec succès."
         respond_with(@listing)  
        end
      end
         ...
  end
```

The form that trigger the create action is rendered via a modal

```
_form.html.erb

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Publication d'annonce</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 
             <%= form_for :listing, :url => {:action => :create} do |f| %>
              <div class="form-group row">
                   <%= f.label :name,"Titre de l'annonce", class: 'col-4 col-form-label'%> 
                <div class="col-8">
                   <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Titre de l'annonce",class: "form-control here" %>  
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <%= f.label :price,"Prix d'offre", class:'col-4 col-form-label'%>
                <div class="col-8">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                      <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
                    </div>
                    <%= f.text_field :price,placeholder: "Prix d'offre" ,class:"form-control here"%>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                 <%= f.label :display_usd ,'Prix en USD', class: 'col-4' %>  
                <div class="col-8">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <%= f.check_box :display_usd, class:'form-check-input' %>
                      USD
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <%= f.label :category_id,class:"col-4 col-form-label" %>
                <div class="col-8">
                  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "choose a category"}, {class: "form-control here"}%>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="select1" class="col-4 col-form-label">Localisation</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                  <select id="select1" name="select1" class="form-control">
                    <option value="rabbit">Rabbit</option>
                    <option value="duck">Duck</option>
                    <option value="fish">Fish</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
               <div class="form-group row">
                <%= f.label :image, "Image Principale", class:'col-4 col-form-label' %>   
                <div class="col-8">
                <%= f.file_field :image, class:'form-control here'%>
                </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Condition</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input name="radio1" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="rabbit">
                            Usé
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input name="radio1" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="duck">
                            Neuf
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input name="radio1" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="fish">
                            normal
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                 <%= f.label :description,'Produit Description', class:'col-4 col-form-label' %> 
                <div class="col-8">
                  <%= f.text_area :description,class:" form-control here " do%>  
                  <span id="textareaHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">veuillez donner une description exacte de votre produit.</span>
                  <%end%>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <%= f.label :image, "Image additionel", class:'col-4 col-form-label' %>   
                <div class="col-8">
                <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true, class:'form-control here'%>
                </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-4">Sauvegarder sans publier</label> 
                <div class="col-8">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input name="radio" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="rabbit">
                            Unpublished
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
            <%= f.button "Publier Produit" , class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right', data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Publication en cours..."} %> 
          </div>
          <%end%>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: use redirect_to , also check @listing.save returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes if you're hitting the `create` action using HTML. `create` doesn't typically have an associated view; you use it to process an entity, and redirect the user elsewhere.

Therefore, you should just be able to use:

```
redirect_to @listing
```

at the end of your controller code.

Using `@listing` is a bit of Rails magic - it would more commonly appear as `redirect_to listing_path(@listing)`.

I.E.

```
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
    if @listing.save
      if params[:images]
          params[:images].each { |image|
            @listing.pictures.create(image: image)
          }
       end
     (@users - [current_user]).each do |user|
        Notification.create(recipient: user, actor: current_user, action: "posted", notifiable: @listing)
     end   
     flash[:notice]= "L'annonce #{@listing.listing_number} a eté publiee avec succès."
     redirect_to @listing 
    end
  end
```

Does that do it?

Another common practice is to have different approaches depending on whether or not an object successfully saves to the db. For example:

```
def create
  @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
  if @listing.save
    ...
    redirect_to @listing, notice: "..."
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Listing failed to save" 
    render :new
  end
end
```

A good way to play about with this is to use the generator to see how Rails handles things by default - you can use the following in the terminal to have a dig around: `rails g controller test_controller`.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: Are you using the first example? If so, it would still occur if the record fails to save - there's no `redirect` / `render` in that for when a record doesn't save. If so, could you try adding an `else` to this, as in the last example? If not, please update your question to include the full trace and I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: sorry i was out of town ,i try with the if...else , no error , the listings was not created and this the log from the console.  ` Listing Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "listings"  WHERE ("listings"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "listings"."slug" = 'demo' LIMIT 1
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/cc8e2791f19382e4553c4b4c5bc77b8f20180204-5071-13bbntn.jpg'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK`

Comment: seems the record was not saved in the database , it rollback , so i just need to debug to see what happen, why the record is not saving .

Comment: Great, glad to hear we're past this error :) Does that mean you've got an answer here @ObedLorisson? From that new error it looks like the problem relates to the image field - I'd recommend putting it into a new question. If you @ me in a comment, happy to take a look!